# Determine If It Is An Inner Product

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be vector space of the real and continuous and differentiable twice functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$
>
> Is $\langle f,g \rangle = f(-\pi)g(-\pi)+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f''(x)g''(x)dx$ an inner product?

$\overline{\langle g,f \rangle} = \langle f,g \rangle$ holds as it is real functions

$\langle \alpha f+\beta g,h \rangle = \alpha \langle f,h \rangle + \beta \langle g,h \rangle$ holds due the distributivity of multiplication and linearity of the integral

$\langle f,f \rangle \geq 0$ and $\langle f,f \rangle = 0 \iff f\equiv 0$ seems to hold true, I have tried using $f=\sin$ and $f=\cos$ and it hold true, but how can I prove It?

Comment: Use `\langle ... \rangle` to get $\langle \ldots \rangle$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x+ \pi$. Then $\langle f,f\rangle=0$. Conclusion ?

Comment: but $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}0dx=C$ can we still say that $<f,f>=0$?

Comment: @gbox That integral is equal to zero...

Comment: @Max because it is $c+2\pi$?

Comment: For $f(x)=x+ \pi$ we have $f(- \pi)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$ for all $x$ .Hence $<f,f>=f(-\pi)^2+\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f''(x)^2dx=0$. But $f \ne 0$. Thus: $<*,*>$ does not define an inner product.

Comment: @gbox I don't think so. If your primitive of $0$ is $F(x)=c$, then, by Barrow, $\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}0\ dx=(c-c) = 0$.

Comment: @gbox the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}0dx$ is not $C$..If we had an indefinite integral then we could say that but here you have a rectangle with length $2\pi$ and height $0$ so the area must be zero not non-zero.

Comment: @MariosGretsas if $F(/pi)=C$ how can we be sure that $F(-\pi)=C$ and not $K$? Thanks!

Comment: @gbox...because $F(x)$ is again a constant function ..i.e for every input the value is always $C$

Comment: @gbox if you are not convinced by my previous arguments then you can prove that the integral of $0$ using the definition of Riemman integration with partitions etc..

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, it is not an inner product! The last statement doesn't hold. Take 
$f(x)=x+\pi$. Then $f\neq 0$ but $\langle f,f\rangle=0$, as

$$ f(-\pi)=0$$

and

$$f''(x)=0$$

...are you sure the exercise is exactly like this?